# How to forward all request in azure appservice to another server

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, azure-appservice

netcore  web app hosted on my server
and i was wondering is it possible to implement reverse proxy in azure app service?
I should mention that i'm quit familiar with the YARP in .net i implement that and is just works perfectly but im looking for a better solution that i dont have to create another web app that includes just a reverse proxy app with YARP ! like a webserver config in azure or something else !

SampleApp.azurewebsite.com ---FORWARD----->https://sample.com or https://ServerIP

Thanks

Comment: Will this answer help you to forward traffic?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1023301/is-it-possible-to-redirect-traffic-from-root-domai.html
https://www.zainrizvi.io/blog/block-default-azure-websites-domain/

Comment: @AndriyBilous Thanks my friend ! is it possible both of them talking about redirecting with web.config through IIS . Is it possible to do that in ubuntu azure  machine?
because my deployment platform in appservice section is ubuntu

Comment: [MattSlater-0658‘s answer should useful to you.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/43630/azure-web-app-to-act-as-a-of-reverse-proxy-with-a.html)

Comment: You will have to define "forward" clearly, redirect or rewrite. But anyway, ASP.NET Core web app can do it natively if you enable the rewriting middleware, https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting